# add a column to existing table whose value is dependent on other column

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I want to add a column to my existing table whose value is dependent on another column STORE. STORE has two values, T or D. If store value is T, then I want the value in added column to be 1, otherwise zero. IS there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not support this on the create or alter table commands.

Instead, use:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD c INTEGER;

UPDATE your_table SET c = CASE WHEN store = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Comment: This solves the immediate matter of "add a column" but doesn't address the ongoing maintenance of the column (to be fair the questioner doesn't raise that either).

Comment: Agreed. It all depends on the ultimate goal. If all you want is a column that maps the T and D values to 0 or 1 then the virtual column or view approaches probably make the most sense. If you're just creating an initial state for the values and an application will be maintaining them going forward, this solution may be the one that makes sense.

Comment: Oracle doesn't recognize the word COLUMN. The first query should be  : ALTER TABLE your_table ADD c INTEGER;

Comment: @Jadenko88: Yup, thank you.  Edited.  Don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

a virtual column can do it in 11g:

```
SQL> create table yourtab (store varchar2(1));

Table created.

SQL> alter table yourtab add col as (case store when 'T' then 1 else 0 end);

Table altered.

SQL> insert into yourtab (store) values ('T');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into yourtab (store) values ('D');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from yourtab;

S        COL
- ----------
T          1
D          0
```

or a trigger approach if your on 10g or before:

```
SQL> create table yourtab (store varchar2(1), col number);

Table created.

SQL> create trigger yourtab_biu
  2  before insert or update on yourtab
  3  for each row
  4  declare
  5  begin
  6    :new.col := case :new.store when 'T' then 1 else 0 end;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into yourtab (store) values ('T');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into yourtab (store) values ('D');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from yourtab;

S        COL
- ----------
T          1
D          0
```

Comment: This is my query 

`alter table rm_saicharan_finalv3do add col as (case store when 'D' then 1 else 0 end);'

It says invalid data type.

Comment: @user2133404 you are on 10g or lower then i assume?

Comment: Im using oracle sql developer

Comment: @user2133404 what is your database version (select * from v$version)? i've put a trigger approach there that will work on all prior versions of Oracle.

Comment: With the 10g implementation I would add a check constraint to enforce the rule.  The need not to do this is another reason why virtual columns are attractive.

Answer (score 1):

A view could be a solution:

```
create view v_your_table as
select  your_table.*, case when STORE = 'T' than 0 else 1 end as comp from your_table;
```

Comment: It gives null value in the column created

Comment: "COMPUTED BY" is Oracle RDB syntax (a product Oracle acquired way back but still a separate thing).  The Oracle RDBMS 11g syntax is different.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#BABIDDJJ

Comment: You are right, I took it from RDB documentation. Shame on me :/